# How will I repeat group header of same group where I only want to repeat the second portion of the group?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

[image]

Here you can see the report. Here you can see the header that is Material Name and so on. Now I want to repeat that header on each page without repeating the details above the Material Header table.

[image]

[image: [![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDkAy.png)

Here the group by is implemented using one attribute. That is why when I changed the second subgroup to Repeat group header on each page it also keeps repeating the details above the material header table. I want only the material table header to be repeated.

Comment: Have you included header of table in section page header?

Comment: I did not understand! Which header are you talking about? Material header?

Comment: yes Material header, that is header of the table

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to repeat Group Header 1b on each page but not Group Header 1a?

Comment: Yes yes! this is what I want! @dd4711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat only a part of a group header there are (at least) two different approaches:

1. multiple (sub-)header on a group and suppressing the unwanted header
2. multiple, identical groups, repeating only some of them

To use multiple group header:

- Create a group a field (PONo) in your case).
- Check `Repeat Group Header On Each Page` in the Group Options in the Group Expert.
- Create group headers for the group (#1a and #1b in your case)
- Add a Suppression Formula for the group header that should not repeat (#1a), put `InRepeatedGroupHeader` in the formula body

This will print both group header when a group is printed first but only group header #1b on following pages.

To use multiple groups:

- Create two groups on the same field (Group 1 and 2 on PONo)
- Check `Repeat Group Header On Each Page` only for group 2

This will print both group header when a group is printed first but only group header #2 on following pages.

Comment: How to use `InRepeatedGroupHeader` in formula can you show me the syntax?

Comment: Just put it in there. `InRepeatedGroupHeader` is a function, returning `true` when a group header is repeated.

Comment: but when I added formula it is stored in a variable! Where will I place that variable in the report section?

Comment: Don't create a formula-you want a conditional suppression. Open the Section Expert for group header #1a. Next to `Suppress` click the formula icon. Add `InRepeatedGroupHeader` as the formula body.